# what does the と particle indicate or mean used before a verb?

Tags: particles, verbs, particle-と, adverbs, japanese-to-english

We're taught that **と** particle is used as **and** & **with** connecting nouns.
**1.** But in this sentence **上司が「一杯、飲もう」と言った** the verb **言った** is followed by  **と**.
And the sentence means [My boss said: "Let's have a drink."]
**2.** The same way please explain this too => **彼はまた電話すると言いました。[He said he'd call again.]**

I'm studying NIHONGO for about 3 months. So as a beginner I don't understand how the と particle is effective and the sentence.

Can anybody tell me clearly why this particle is being used here. I've never seen it before. Thank youu for your time!

Comment: This does a little bit. But not crystal clear. I'm still confused. Thanks though!

Comment: Just as a general note... basically every particle has many usages. You mentioned one of them for と that you had learned, but there are a handful. https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8